# tree shaking node_modules in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js

I have a private npm package that I am importing into my Next app.

```
import { Button } from 'private-npm-package'
```

I am not using any of the other components except Button in my app. When I analyze the output I see other components/js files from this package being included in the build output. This makes the bundle size bigger. My understanding is tree shaking is enabled by default. Doesn't tree shaking happen inside node_modules? Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong? How can I remove those files/components that I don't use from the build output ?
I have a custom .babelrc as below:

```
{
  "presets": [
   "next/babel"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is the private-npm-package using / exporting ES6 modules or is it bundled/transpiled into commonjs/umd/etc.? Could it be using [side-effects](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#clarifying-tree-shaking-and-sideeffects)?

Comment: Are you using target serverless in next.config?

Comment: @Narigo - the package is bundled/transpiled into commonjs. I see require statements in the transpiled file.

Comment: @evgenifotia - I am not using target serverless in next.config.

Comment: Then as @Narigo said you need to use ES2015 module syntax. for more info https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/

Comment: thank you - that makes sense